# Is it possible to call a function inside an attribute?

Tags: xslt

I can't find out how one can call an extension function in a code like that:

```
<xsl:if test='string-length(normalize-space(body)) &gt; 100'>
    <a href='/photo/{id}-'> &gt;&gt;&gt;</a><br/>
</xsl:if>
```

I need to add a call to my `foo:translit(human_url)` function after `'{id}-'` so the result would read `'/photo/{id}-{transliterated_part}'`, but there seems to be no syntactically correct way to do so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly possible. Just casually call your function wrapped in curly braces, something like :

```
<a href='/photo/{id}-{foo:translit(human_url)}'> &gt;&gt;&gt;</a>
```

Here is a demo using user-defined function `foo:upper-lower()`, which return upper-case and lower-case version of the received parameter, separated with underscore :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform exclude-result-prefixes="foo xs" xmlns:foo="bar" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:function name="foo:upper-lower" as="xs:string">
      <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="concat(upper-case($input),'_',lower-case($input))"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="a">
      <a href="/photo/{.}-{foo:upper-lower(.)}"></a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**<kbd>[`xsltransform.net demo`](http://xsltransform.net/94rmq6B)</kbd>**

**input :**

```
<a>Test</a>
```

**output :**

```
<a href="/photo/Test-TEST_test"/>
```